# calling ls and other using execve

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a simple program that will allow to execute basic
shell commands. Problem is execve just hangs everytime.

Heres the code:

```
    char* arglist[]={"ls","-l",NULL};
    char* env[]={NULL};
    int status;
    while (1)
    {
        if (fork() != 0)
        {
            waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            execve(arglist[0],arglist,env);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: should be `if (fork() > 0)` since `fork` may fail

Comment: This has nothing to do with `bash`. `ls` is not a "shell command", it's just a command. (It's specified in the "shell and utilities" section of the POSIX spec, yes, but it's a utility, not a part of the shell).

Comment: ...also, when working in C, always check your return values (and `errno` when appropriate) and call `perror` when something is unsuccessful; you probably wouldn't have needed to ask this question if you'd looked at the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first arguments should be a full path to the binary you execute:

```
char* arglist[]={"/bin/ls", "-l", NULL};
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. How can I make it work without the full path?

Comment: You can't. `execve()` requires the full path.